# How to rename files in a batch loop

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am currently writing a script for compressing mp3 songs in a directory. It looks like this.

```
SET BITRATE=128k
SET EXTENSION=mp3
SET MP3_CODEC=libmp3lame

for %%f in (.\*.%EXTENSION%) do (
    ffmpeg -y -i "%%f" -acodec %MP3_CODEC% -ab %BITRATE% -id3v2_version 3 "%%f.%EXTENSION%"
    del "%%f"
    ren "%%f.%EXTENSION%" "%%f"
)
```

Which works fine on compressing and deleting the original file. But at the time of **renaming the new file** I get a `The syntax of the command is incorrect` error.

Isolated, the failing code is this

```
for %%f in (.\*.mp3) do ren "%%f" "%%f.mp3"
```

I know the renaming workaround seems bad but the `%%f` variable stores the folder on it (i.e. ".\song.mp3") so I cannot change the name of the file, just its extension (which must be the same for ffmpeg to work).

### Repeating the error

Having installed ffmpeg in Windows, place a X.mp3 file and this script in a folder and run the script. It will compress the file onto a new file called "X.mp3.mp3", deleted the original "X.mp3" file and fail at the time of renaming "X.mp3.mp3" to "X.mp3".

If I run those commands manually in a console it does work.

Comment: remove the `.\ `. It is part of `%%f` (and is not needed), which explains the issue.

Comment: or `ren "%%f.%EXTENSION%" "%%~nxf"` (with `ren` the destination can only be a file name (no path))

Comment: Thank you very much! I did that because of a tutorial, but now it works perfectly.

Comment: Instead of deleting and renaming you could do this: `move /Y "%%f.%EXTENSION%" "%%f"` (append `> nul` to hide the summary `1 file(s) moved.`)

Comment: For those looking for a working solution I have created a gist with it - https://gist.github.com/gomezportillo/0211eeecc67eb6a46e69dae59367c26d